# Why does my code not account for large numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm defining this function to find the exp of base**exp that is closest to the num specified. The only problem is that it doesn't work in case you input a large value for num.

If you input nearest_power(2, 192.0) you should get 7 but instead the code returns nothing.

```
def nearest_power(base, num):

   exp = 0

   while base**exp < num:
       exp += 1

   if num < base:
       return 0    
   elif num - base**(exp-1) < base**exp - num:
       return exp - 1
   elif base**exp - num < num - base**(exp-1):
       return exp
   else:
    return exp - 1
```

Comment: `print(nearest_power(3,28.6))` => 3. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Doesn't work in case of nearest_power(2, 192.0) and closest_power(5, 375.0)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample input, expected output, the actual output, and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: Never mind. It's working now. It wasn't working before for some reason >-> Weird.